# Solve and equation for 2 variables

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A bit of background: I'm writing a report in a piece of software and have to use XSLT1.0 (no extensions supported). What this means is that I only have basic arithmetic functions and a few simple functions like "mod"

My maths is pretty rusty, but here's the problem (for 2 variables, but there could be more)

We are a manufacturing plant.

Manufacturing need 150 copies of X and 400 copies of Y and they have determined that the optimum method was to put 2 copies of X per sheet and 4 copies of y per sheet and to produce 100 sheets.

The total copies produced is therefore 200 of X and 400 of Y. (There are 50 waste copies of X, as we only need 150 and produced 200. Because of a very expensive setup process, this is the cheapest option.)

I need to create job instructions (in XSLT1.0) that tells the operator how many sheets to produce, but the XML (my source data) only has the following info

X is 2up
Y is 4up 
There are 550 net pieces.

Somehow I need to figure out that this is 600 total pieces and 100 sheets. This is where I'm stuck.

The only hint I have is that I have no waste of (at least 1 piece) and the answer will be two integers

Anyone got any ideas how to go about solving this

Regards

Mark

Comment: You know that you have to place 2X + 4Y in every sheet and you know that you have 600 pieces in total and that you have 100 sheets. What is missing? Are you looking for integer soultions (values of X, Y) for 2X+4Y<=600?

Comment: @NoChance - I DON'T know that I have 600 pieces, as I mentioned in my post. All I have in the XML is that X is 2up Y is 4up There are 550 net pieces.